# How to Use foreach with 2 array variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have codes like this

```
    <?php
        include "assets/config/connect.php";

            foreach( $_POST['nim'] as $nim ){
                $kode_mk= $_POST['kode_mk'] ;
                $nilai= $_POST['nilai'] ;
                $tahun_akademik= $_POST['tahun_akademik'] ;
                $sql = " INSERT INTO nilai (nim, kode_mk, nilai, tahun_akademik, id_nilai) VALUES ('$nim', '$kode_mk', '$nilai', '$tahun_akademik', NULL) ";        
                if (!mysql_query($sql)){
                    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
                }                   
            }
?>
```

but the result is not same with my expectation

this is the result [image]

please help me

Comment: What does `$_POST` array look like and what is the expected outcome here ?

Comment: Show `$_POST` array. then only any one can assist anythig

Comment: Yes it would be very helpful to do `print_r($_POST);` to see array contents info and post that here.

Comment: I get a $ _POST the contents of the form are the same make and serve an array like this: <input type = "text" name = "nim []" /> and
I do not understand how to enter data into the database if more than one variable associated array because foreach that I know can only accommodate one array

please help me

Answer (score 0):

### The Error

So assuming `kode_mk, nilai, tahun_akademik` are all arrays in `$_POST` you are trying to insert the object of an array as a string. First convert the array to a string using a function like [implode()](http://php.net/implode).

### Solution: Using PHP Implode()

```
$array = array('hi', 'my', 'name', 'is');
$string = implode(',', $array); // string = 'hi,my,name,is'
```

Implode works like this `implode(glue, array)` the glue is a string that is inserted between each element of the array to separate them in a string. You can use `explode(delimiter, string)` to then reverse the string to an array!

### Example Using your code

```
    <?php
    include "assets/config/connect.php";

        foreach( $_POST['nim'] as $nim ){
            $kode_mk= implode(', ', $_POST['kode_mk']);
            $nilai= implode(', ', $_POST['nilai']);
            $tahun_akademik= implode(', ', $_POST['tahun_akademik']);

            $sql = " INSERT INTO nilai (nim, kode_mk, nilai, tahun_akademik, id_nilai) VALUES ('$nim', '$kode_mk', '$nilai', '$tahun_akademik', NULL) ";        
            if (!mysql_query($sql)){
                die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
            }                   
        }
?>
```

### Notes:

- Try Using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) not the mysql extension for security reasons mentioned by: @messy
- Looks like you are looping over `$_POST['nim']`, but then pulling the same $_POST values for the columns of the database.
- We could really use the format and syntax of the `$_POST` variable

Comment: I get a $ _POST the contents of the form are the same make and serve an array like this: <input type = "text" name = "nim []" /> and
I do not understand how to enter data into the database if more than one variable associated array because foreach that I know can only accommodate one array

please help me

Comment: Show us the exact output of the $_POST in a code tag in an edit to the original post and I will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$kode_mk = $_POST['kode_mk'];
$nilai = $_POST['nilai'];
$tahun_akademik = $_POST['tahun_akademik'];
```

all variables are arrays, not strings as you expect, you should

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

to see the entire structure of POST array

Comment: I get a $ _POST the contents of the form are the same make and serve an array like this: <input type = "text" name = "nim []" /> and
I do not understand how to enter data into the database if more than one variable associated array because foreach that I know can only accommodate one array

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have to show us what your input data looks like. You can do that with `print_r()` or `var_dump()`:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

From the looks of it, your form inputs are arrays (checkboxes?) and you need to either pull them together into a single string or use each one separately.

Also, there is no reason to continue to gather your POST values inside the loop if there is no change in their values. Pull them up outside the loop.

Finally, the mysql_ extension is deprecated and highly discouraged - you shouldn't be using it to write new code. You also need to validate and sanitize your data before doing any inserts. Easiest way to do the latter is parameterized queries.

Comment: I get a $ _POST the contents of the form are the same make and serve an array like this: <input type = "text" name = "nim []" /> and
I do not understand how to enter data into the database if more than one variable associated array because foreach that I know can only accommodate one array

please help me

Comment: So why haven't you tried what everyone here suggested? echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>"; Also so the inputs for your OTHER form elements, not the one that's working fine (although it should NOT have a space in the name attribute before the [] brackets)